# Improve regular expression to match an url containing an alphanumeric word that has at least N letters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've done a regular expression to match urls following the next pattern:

```
part1-part2-part3.html
```

where

part1: is a common word
part2: is an alphanumeric word with underscores, that at least contains 2 letters
part3: is a numeric word, with 1 to 10 digits

for example a valid url would be:

```
news-my_news_title_200_is-12345.html
```

so 
part1 = news
part2 = my_news_title_200_is
part3 = 12345

I've come to this:

```
/^[a-z]+-([a-z0-9_]*(?=[a-z]{2,})[a-z0-9_]*).-([0-9]{1,10})\.html$/
```

Expressed with classes:

```
/^\w+-([\w\d_]*(?=\w{2,})[\w\d_]*).-(\d{1,10})\.html$/
```

But I guess there's a better way to express part2 of the R.E. pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One obvious saving is to use shortcuts rather than ranges, so `\w` for alpha-numeric characters, `\d` for numerical characters etc

Comment: I know that, but I'm refering the lookahead expression in part 2

Comment: Do the 2 letters need to be consecutive or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
\b(?is)[a-z]+-\w*(?=[a-z]{2,})\w*-[0-9]{1,10}\.html\b
```

or

```
^(?is)[a-z]+-\w*(?=[a-z]{2,})\w*-[0-9]{1,10}\.html$
```

**Play it [here](http://regexr.com?31nac)**

Comment: \w{2,} should contain numbers and underscores also

Comment: @FeidaKila: Oh! my missed that. Updated, test it.

Comment: this is ok, thanks for the link. is the same as mine but more clear. is there anyway to express this '\w*(?=[a-z]{2,})\w*' more simple?

Comment: May be you you could use ``[0-9a-z_]*[a-z]{2,}[0-9a-z_]*`` without any ``lookahead`` at all.

Comment: sure, but if i want the letters not to be mandatory consecutive

Comment: Then you could simply use ``\w*``, nothing more!

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+-\w{2,}-\d{1,10}\.html\b
```

more stronger(avoid part2 match only numbers):

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+-(?!\d+-)\w{2,}-\d{1,10}\.html\b
```

Comment: \w{2,} does not contain numbers and underscores

Comment: if you might worry this problem, please see my newest modification.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match 2 non consecutive letters, you can do (example given in perl but it works with languages that understand PCRE)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;

my $re = qr/^\w+-(\w*?[a-z]+\w*?[a-z]+\w*?)-\d+\.html$/;
say YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( $re )->explain;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say ($_ =~ $re ? "match : $_" : "not match : $_");
}
__DATA__
news-my_news_title_200_is-12345.html
news-m_200_s-12345.html
news-m_200-12345.html
```

**output:**

```
match : news-my_news_title_200_is-12345.html
match : news-m_200_s-12345.html
not match : news-m_200-12345.html
```

**Explanation of regular expression:**

```
(?-imsx:^\w+-(\w*?[a-z]+\w*?[a-z]+\w*?)-\d+\.html$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*?                     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*?                     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*?                     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  html                     'html'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks for posting this solution, may be worthy for other users, but not me coz i need it for mod_rewrite